# golang: strange issue with coroutines and channels

Tags: go, channel, coroutine

I wrote a test code, but do not understand why I get this result.

My `sub()` should update or return `counter`, based on the channel value

```
send 1 = counter++
send 0 = return counter
```

I start 10 go routines `con()`.
They should simply send many 1 to channel (this increase counter)
I wait 1 sec and send 0 to channel. What value should I get?

I think first, I get a "random" value,
but i get 100000 (ok 10x 10000 is faster than 1 sec)

Now I change

```
for i:=0; i < 10; i++ {
```

to

```
for i:=0; i < 10000; i++ {
```

and now my returned value is 1

*Why!?*

Now uncomment `fmt.Println(counter)` in `main()`.
As you see counter works and has this "random" number

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var ch chan int = make(chan int)
var counter int

func main() {
    go sub()

    for i:=0; i < 10; i++ { //change to 10000
        go con()
    }

    time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)

    ch <- 0
    fmt.Println(<- ch)
    //fmt.Println(counter) //uncomment this
}

func sub() {
    for c := range ch {
        if c == 0 { ch <- counter }
        if c == 1 { counter++ }
    }
}

func con() {
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        ch <- 1
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because you cannot tell if the `main` or `sub` will pull first from `ch`. Use different channels for sending commands and data.

Comment: with 2 channels, this works!
but where is the logic?
ch is used 10x parallel with con() and 1x with sub() for send
and only 1x in sub for receive.
i do not understand this.

Comment: ah... wait, slowly i understand it... thank you zerkms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with 2 channels, this work:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var ch chan int = make(chan int)
var ch2 chan int = make(chan int)
var counter int

func main() {
    go sub()

    for i:=0; i < 10000; i++ { //change to 10000
        go con()
    }

    time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)

    ch2 <- 0
    fmt.Println(<- ch2)
    //fmt.Println(counter) //uncomment this
}

func sub() {
    for ;; {
        select {
        case <- ch:
            counter++
        case <- ch2:
            ch2 <- counter
        }
    }
}

func con() {
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        ch <- 1
    }
}
```